# Superfish menu - Responsive problems

Tags: theming, navigation

I am building my site using drupal 7 and adaptivetheme.

Before I used superfish module, my main menu was very responsive and works great across all sizes.

Now, I started to use superfish (latest version) for the dropdown in my horizontal main menu, and the menu is not responsive. when I am resizing the window, the right tab of the menu is moving below the menu, instead of the text will get smaller.
but, If I resize just a little more it  looks like the text is getting smaller for less then a seconed, and than all the horizontal menu (6 tabs) become one dropdown with all the tabs inside.
I know that in a very small screen the menu is collapsing to one drop down, but why does it happen in a size of landscape tablet (and even a little bigger)?

How can I make my superfish main menu responsive, and become smaller (like the rest of the site) when the window size is getting smaller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get into your Superfish menu block (find from the block admin page: `/admin/structure/block` usually the specific address is: `/admin/structure/block/manage/superfish/1/configure`.

There under "Superfish plugins" -> "sf-smallscreen" -> "window width settings" and change the breakpoint value; make it smaller (default is 768 pixels).